# Is it possible to sign an MSI after making updates to values in a table?

Tags: windows-installer

I have an MSI that is downloadable from a web site.  Currently, values in the MSI are updated (installation configuration) when the installer is downloaded.  The only problem is that the MSI won't be signed after doing this (if it already was).

Is there a way to sign the installer without having to re-build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method and a standard used by deployment engineers is to [create a MST file](http://tonyle.ca/blog/?p=33) and [deploy the MSI together with the MST](http://www.klaus-hartnegg.de/gpo/mst.html).

The MST can contain new properties or updated values for existing properties and have them applied over your MSI installation, without affecting the contents of the original MSI package, thus its digital signature remains valid.

Comment: This is a superior solution to what I've proposed above, I'll give this a shot and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides a utility called signtool.exe that can be used for this purpose.

**To sign a Windows Installer file (.msi)**

On the development computer, install the certificate that you want to sign the file with.

Open a Visual Studio command prompt.
Change to the directory that contains the .msi file.
Sign the .msi file by using the following command:

```
signtool sign /sha1 CertificateHash SetupFile.msi
```

For example, to sign a setup file that is named ExcelAddInSetup.msi, use the following command:

```
signtool sign /sha1 CCB... ExcelAddInSetup.msi
```

**To sign a Setup program (.exe)**

On the development computer, install the certificate that you want to sign the file with.
Open a Visual Studio command prompt.
Change to the directory that contains the .exe file.
Sign the .exe file by using the following command:

```
signtool sign /sha1 CertificateHash Setup.exe
```

For example, to sign the Setup program, use the following command:
signtool sign /sha1 CCB... Setup.exe

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee290833(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want to give your certificate to your customers because that would allow them to sign anything with your certificate and effectively use your certificate identity.

Without knowing exactly how the modifications are being made, it's difficult to be sure this would work, but you can alter the MSI with custom actions after it's been launched but before it uses the table contents. If you wanted to add rows to the Property table, as an example, you would have a custom action that updates the (now in-memory) MSI by adding those rows to the Property table before any custom actions that use the properties.